# Why does TCP endpoint disconnection throws a bunch of 0 bytes on the other endpoint?

Tags: c#, sockets, tcp

I was playing around with Sockets and TCP in C# and this happened. When one endpoint of the connection disconnects, the other when using Receive method gets a bunch of zero bytes. Why does that happen?

This is the code (ran with dotnet script) that can reproduce what I mentioned:

```cs
using System;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Sockets;
                    
Socket s = new Socket(SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);
s.Bind(new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Any, 1000));
s.Listen(1);
Console.WriteLine("Opened.");

Socket c = new Socket(SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);
c.Connect(new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Loopback, 1000));

Socket i = s.Accept();
Console.WriteLine("Accepted.");

byte[] buffer = Array.Empty<byte>();

i.Shutdown(SocketShutdown.Both);

while (true)
{
    buffer = new byte[4];
    c.Receive(buffer, 4, SocketFlags.None);
    Console.WriteLine(BitConverter.ToString(buffer).Replace("-"," "));
}
```

When the problem happens the console will print a lot of `00 00 00 00` sequences. It happens with `i` and `c` swapped too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ... the other when using Receive method gets a bunch of zero bytes

That's the wrong interpretation due to the wrong code. What is printed out is the content of the original zero-initialized buffer. The buffer was unchanged within `c.Receive` since the call did not receive anything.

What should have been done is to check the [return value of `Receive`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.sockets.socket.receive?view=net-5.0#System_Net_Sockets_Socket_Receive_System_Byte___System_Int32_System_Int32_System_Net_Sockets_SocketFlags_) which is the amount of bytes actually read. It would have shown that nothing code returned. Instead it was simply but wrongly assumed that 4 bytes were read because 4 bytes were asked for.

In general `Receive` can always return less bytes than asked for, not only at connection close. Thus only as much bytes from the `buffer` should be considered read from the peer as explicitly returned as *bytes received* by `Receive`.

Comment: Does that mean this Receive overload does not block until received the given amount of bytes? Does it only receive as much as it can once and then return?

Comment: @TrietVoNguyenMinh: `Receive` will block until it received at least one byte or until it is clear that no bytes at all can be received (i.e. connection closed or error). To cite from the documentation I've linked to: *"If you are using a connection-oriented Socket, the Receive method will read __as much data as is available, up to the number of bytes specified by the size parameter__. If the remote host shuts down the Socket connection with the Shutdown method, and all available data has been received, the Receive method will complete immediately and return zero bytes."*